# using powershell to only read last 1month of folders. copy in 7 days worth of folders then using robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy

apologies to start as im new to powershell and robocopy.
i have a robocopy command that pulls in any files within its many subfolders that are within a maxage of 7. however, the main folder has a huge amount of folders dating back years(and i only need last 7 days each week it runs) so its slow reading each file in each folder before it even copies using robocopy.

it looks like powershell commands may be a way for me to limit the search of files for my robocopy, would this be possible? currently robocopy search each files in each folder in my main folder, ideally i would want it to be smart enough to only search even a months worth of files and then copy over last 7 days. this would speed up the run time hugely.

if possible even further, i only want csv files in each of the folders in my main folder but current robocopy searches the other folders and its files as well which takes time. all the csv files are in a folder called "run" in each parent folder(parent folder is a unique number within the "mainfolder".

my robocopy command:

```
robocopy \\server\mainfolder \\server\new_main_folder /S /maxage:7 /r:0 /w:0
```

Comment: [1] take a look at this robocopy option >>> `/XD dirs [dirs]... :: eXclude Directories matching given names/paths.` <<<. ///// [2] ANYTHING that excludes a subset of your files will need to read those files to find the ones to exclude [or to just include]. [*grin*] so PoSh aint gonna help with that since powershell is SLOW when compared to robocopy. i suggest you reorganize your files to allow you to target a smaller dir tree.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to point to you either FastCopy or [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/), both handle long file name paths and work well for me.  But found problems running FastCopy when trying to filter folders the way you described. I wasn't getting the results I expected, so that leaves FreeFileSync.  There is a little bit of a learning curve with FreeFileSync, but really, the only problem/complaint I've had with it is the xml based batch script that you can use to automate the program kept changing formats and they haven't been providing a way to read the old xml batch scripts with the new version of the software.  Maybe that has changed, I haven't looked into that lately.

Maybe other people have had better experience with RoboCopy, but I found it to take literally many multiples longer to do the same job as many other copy programs.  I don't think FreeFileSync is as fast as FastCopy, but I've never seen it act as bad as what I experienced with RoboCopy.

The way FreeFileSync works is:

1. You define 1 or more source/destination pairs.
2. There is a global setting at the top to set the defaults for all copy pairs.
3. There are individual settings per each copy pair that when set override the global settings.
4. In the filter tab of the settings you can set "Time span:" to "Last x days:" and set it to the 7 days that you want.
5. You can change include from * to something like \run\*.csv.  I didn't try that exact pattern, but the patterns I did try worked as expected (Unlike FastCopy).
6. The Synchronization tab is the tricky/fun one.  You can do logs, versioning, tell the system to shutdown or restart when done, maintain a database for tracking moved files ("Detect moved files" checkbox), and all kinds of adjustments to how it behaves when files don't match.
7. When done, there is I believe at least 2 options for saving the configuration - though I've always just created the xml based batch script and called that from another scripting language or an icon on the desktop.